# A working website suddenly started throwing connection refused

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, connection

I know this question is probaly repationg question. But all the other questions had a different solution that did not work for me. Here is the screeshot of my error

[image]

I tried to change `DB_HOST=localhost` into `DB_HOST=127.0.0.1` but it did not work, and I also tried to change url into **https** it seem to make no difference. Any help is appreciated in advance.

Comment: try connecting it manually using mysql -p password -u username in the console

Comment: You mean the server console? @vSugumar

Comment: Yes check it and post it result

Comment: Let me see if I can access the console. I never used the console in this server. It's pretty low class

Comment: do you have access to phpmyadmin

Comment: yeah I do have access to php my admin

Comment: is there any error connecting to phpmyadmin

Comment: No sir, there is none. That is the weird part.

Comment: Also there was no error when I first launched the website

Comment: ok try accessing it in the console; and if you can access run this command to know the port: SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'PORT';

Comment: ok so in phpmyadmin console I tried to run `mysql -u [username] -p [password]` and it's throwing error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176464/discussion-between-v-sugumar-and-nikonah).